# How would I find out about color similarity between different images in ruby?

Tags: ruby, image, image-processing

Let's assume, I had a bunch of colorful pictures and I wanted to group them by their predominant color. So that in the end I get all blueish pictures, yellowish, greenish, greyish and whateverish as different groups, a bit like google image search can do it. Also I do not want groups with less than, say, 3 pictures and put pictures falling into these groups into the next best color group (So I also need group similarity).

How would I go about this? I have no idea.

In Ruby.

Comment: I'd start by reading through this: http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/

Comment: From the FAQ: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: I could remove the last question, but I doubt this would make much difference. The problem ist similar, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a color histogram with an euclidean distance to measure the color similarity between images.  [Click here](http://scien.stanford.edu/pages/labsite/2002/psych221/projects/02/sojeong/) and search for Color histogram definition.  It's a pretty simple approach for such problem